# Install4j missing digest in RPM archives

Tags: fedora, rpm, checksum, install4j, digest

`rpm` files produced with install4j are missing the digest by default. This forces the user to use the `--nodigest` flag when installing them. Is there a way to tell install4j to generate the checksum for `rpm` files?

Comment: The created RPM files do include an MD5 signature, what is the error message  that you're getting without `--nodigest`?

Comment: I'm getting this:

`package app-2.1.2.05ead4a1-1.x86_64 does not verify: no digest`

Comment: What is the output of `rpm --checksig <rpm name> --nodigest`?

Comment: `app_linux_2_1_4_71511391.rpm: OK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 7.0.8, the digest is done with MD5 which is no longer acceptable in recent versions of rpm. This will be fixed in install4j 7.0.9 where SHA-1 and SHA-256 signatures will be generated as well.

Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Release 7.0.9 was published on 2019.01.09 and includes the bugfix:
"RPM archives now include SHA-1 and SHA-256 digests to avoid warnings on recent Linux distributions"
See https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/install4j/changelog.html